# Compile GPL-code into a JNI-capable shared library and use it in commercial software

Tags: java, c, android, gpl, closed-source

I am developing an application for Android in JAVA which calls GPLed C-code via JNI.

I have modified & capsulated a GPL-software under a JNI-interface and compile it as a shared library (.so) which I can use via JNI from my JAVA-part (the commercial part with closed source).

Because I have stripped the original GPL-software from everything which is not needed by my software, that GPL-software has no more other GPL-dependencies which explicitly forbid using it as a shared library in a closed-source software (like SecretRabbitCode for example forbids it).

I have no problem to set my modified version of the GPL-software online, but I cannot do this with my commercial software.

Because I need the modified version of the GPL-software in my software, I have to bundle it in one package (a APK-file in Android).

Sadly, the GPL-software has 1 or 2 more dependencies to GPL-code (just C-files like aes.c), so it's not as easy as just ask the author of this GPL-software.

Because the Android-way of "packing JAVA and .so-files together, bundle it and distribute it" is quite new, it's not as easy as with pure JAVA or pure C code.

Who can help out?

Comment: Even if you'd distribute it as separate .so files within an archive, GPL (as opposed to LGPL) usually affects the whole software, and not just that single .so file. So I think calling a GPLed .so file from your closed source application isn't possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to release your entire Software under the GPL, otherwise you'll be violating the terms of the license. A JNI wrapper most emphatically does not isolate you from the requirements of the GPL.